# Add all the items for an attribute in DynamoDb to ElasticCache or Aws memory db for fast lookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, elastic-cache, amazon-memory-db

I would appreciate some insights if this is a good/bad design choice.

I have a Dynamodb with an attribute of which all of which have to be fetched for an access pattern.

Instead of doing a parallel scan, would it be OK to write through in elastic cache(Redis set) so that it can looked up instantly?

Comment: "Instead of doing a parallel scan, would it be OK to write through in elastic cache(Redis set) so that it can looked up instantly?" Yes, why would that not be OK?

Comment: How many items will typically be in this table?

Comment: @MarkB I am fairly new to trying caching, couldn't find it to be a common use case so I wasn't sure if this could be an anti pattern

Comment: @jarmod I think initially 10K items each of size 100bytes at max

Comment: @ShivamThakur it's such a common use case that Amazon built an entire service just to accomplish this common thing, it's called DynamoDB DAX.  https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/ But depending on the pricing and your specific usage you might be better off using Redis ElastiCache.

Comment: @MarkB I see, thanks for your inputs! Btw would Redis open door to many other caching needs compared to DAX setup specifically for dynamoDB